# How to center the content of a div with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap and I am in the process of getting to know it. I am trying to position a dropdown menu just in the center of the page, I manage to center the link that toggles the menu but this menu shows out of place.

This is what I tried:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a id ="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Despliega menú<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" target="_blank">Mi Web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <!-- /div.dropdown -->
    </div>
    <!-- /div.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /div.row -->
</div>
<!-- /div.container -->
```

Obviously the link is center because I am using `.text-center` for the div containing everything, I have tried using the class `center-block` but it doesn't help. Any hints?

Comment: So you're trying to center the div with the class `.dropdown`, right?

Comment: I want to center the whole dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dropdown is a block element, aligning it with text-align:center will not work on block elements. try adding display: inline-block on dropdown div. check out the jsfiddle ex. http://jsfiddle.net/kuyabiye/KLH8S/

```
<style>
    .dropdown-center {
       text-align: center;

    }

    .dropdown-center .dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 dropdown-center">
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a id ="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Despliega menú<span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="www.stackoverflow.com" target="_blank">Stack Overflow</a>
          </li>
          <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
          <li role="presentation">
            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" target="_blank">Mi Web</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <!-- /div.dropdown -->
    </div>
    <!-- /div.col-md-4 .col-md-offset-4 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /div.row -->
</div>
<!-- /div.container -->
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem; but is there no class in Bootstrap that already does that? Is it really necessary to do it "manually"?

Comment: I don't think there is a class for that.